# Having Difficulty Integrating JSON Library with My AVR Microcontroller Code

Tags: c, codeblocks, avr, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I am a relatively inexperienced C developer with no previous experience in integrating libraries made by other developers into existing projects.

Basically, I need a means of parsing JSON data in an AVR microcontroller for a university project. To this end I attempted to download and integrate jansson (https://github.com/akheron/jansson) into my existing build of the microcontroller code. I am working with Atmel Studio in Windows 10, but I have also installed Code::Blocks with MinGW GCC (on the same Windows 10 installation) for the purpose of building the library, and to attempt to integrate the library into a native Windows application. So far, neither has been successful, and I get the same errors. All of the online resources I've found so far have been to basic to be useful, or well beyond my comprehension.

This is what I have done thus far:

I began by attempting to build the software and then integrate it into an existing project per the instructions in https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.11/gettingstarted.html. I installed CMake, built the project files for Code::Blocks with cmake.exe -G “CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles”, then opened the project and built everything. A few of the targets (I believe related to testing) failed to build, but jansson itself built and output libjansson.a to the \lib\ directory, so I didn’t think too much of it.

That is as far as I’ve been able to get. In both Atmel Studio and Code::Blocks, I do the same thing: add jansson.h to the relevant include paths, add #include “jansson.h” to all of the relevant files, and add libjansson.a as a library in each IDE’s respective linker options. I’ve tried various things like adding and removing flags to the linker, but the output is always “cannot find -ljansson”, “undefined reference to ‘json_object_seed’” (which is a function in the API I’m calling for no reason other than to see if the project has built properly) and/or “ld returned 1 exit status”.

I cannot help but feel as if the issue is with the line “cc -o prog prog.c -ljansson” in the documentation linked above. I really just don’t understand how to set up the linker properly to get the project to build.

If anyone could give some insight into what I’m doing wrong/the correct way to link this library I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The library itself should be built with appropriate toolchain. I assume that you built your library twice, one version using MinGW toolchain and other with avr-gcc toolchain.

If you compile target application and linker cannot find library, then try to add path of directory that contains *.a file of library to linker settings (linker search path). Let's say you have: `/path/to/lib/libjansson.a`

In Code::Blocks: `Project → Build options → Search directories → Linker` add `/path/to/lib/`. Then it should link with include path set, for example: `cc -o prog prog.c -ljansson -L/path/to/lib/`

In Atmel Studio when you add a library in `Solution Explorer → Libraries → Add Library` it should automatically add library search path to linker options. If you check `Project → Properties → AVR/GNU Linker` there should be (between other options): `-Wl,-ljansson -Wl,-L"/path/to/lib/"`

If you copied library files (libjansson.a and jansson.h) to your application's project directory, it will be convenient to use relative paths to library files.